# ¿Cómo obtener las monedas disponibles restando las ventas y comisiones a las compras en 2 tablas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, inner

Estoy haciendo una base de datos en Access para el control de compra-venta de criptomonedas. Ya tengo implantado el método FIFO, introducción de datos y demás.

Quiero mostrar en el formulario de venta las monedas disponibles cuando se elige una para introducir una venta, pero no consigo dar con la consulta correcta.

Tengo 2 tablas, *COMPRA* y *VENTA*. Quiero restarle al campo *CANTIDAD* de *COMPRA* la suma de los campos *CANTIDAD* y *COMISION* de *VENTA* para cada moneda diferente.

He probado un `LEFT JOIN` (para que la consulta muestre también el saldo de las monedas que aún no tienen ventas), pero lo que obtengo es que para cada ocurrencia de una moneda en el campo cantidad de *COMPRA* me suma todas las cantidades y comisiones de *VENTA*, por lo que el resultado no es correcto:

```
Select COMPRA.MONEDA, Sum(compra.cantidad) as COMPRAS, Sum(venta.cantidad) AS VENTAS, sum(venta.comision) as COMISION, COMPRAS-VENTAS-COMISION as SALDO
From COMPRA left join Venta on COMPRA.moneda=VENTA.moneda
group by COMPRA.MONEDA
```

También he probado usando `WHERE`, pero tampoco obtengo nada correcto:

```
Select COMPRA.MONEDA, compra.cantidad as COMPRAS, Sum(venta.cantidad) AS VENTAS, sum(venta.comision) as COMISION, COMPRAS-VENTAS-COMISION as SALDO
From COMPRA, venta
where compra.moneda=venta.moneda
group by COMPRA.MONEDA order by compra.moneda
```

Seguro que para los expertos que hay por aquí es una tontería, pero no doy con ello. Gracias por adelantado!

---

Actualizo, consigo que me calcule bien las existencias de las monedas que tienen cantidad introducida en compras y en ventas, pero de las que aún no tienen ventas, me salen en el resultado pero con cantidad vacía (lo que esperaría es que me saliera el total disponible (suma de cantidades compradas)).

Por si podéis ver dónde estaría el error. Gracias

---

Vuelvo a responderme, añadiendo un UNION con las monedas que tienen ventas, ya me sale:

```
SELECT C.moneda as MONEDA, SUM(COMPRAS - VENTAS) AS SALDO
FROM (SELECT moneda, sum(cantidad) AS COMPRAS FROM compra GROUP BY moneda) C INNER JOIN (SELECT moneda, sum(cantidad) + sum(comision) AS VENTAS FROM venta GROUP BY moneda) V ON c.moneda=v.moneda
GROUP BY C.MONEDA

union

SELECT MONEDA, CANTIDAD as saldo from compra where moneda not in (select moneda from venta)
```

Comment: ¿Es "access" o SQL Server? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, recuerda borrar tu _no-respuesta_. Si necesitas agregar aclaraciones, debes editar tu pregunta.

Comment: Perfecto, disculpad las molestias, no lo había visto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de manera sencilla con un `UNION ALL` para que quede explícito lo que intentas hacer.

```
SELECT moneda,
       SUM(compras) as compras, 
       SUM(ventas) as ventas, 
       SUM(comision) as comision,
       SUM( compras - ventas - comision) AS saldo
FROM (
    SELECT  moneda, 
            SUM(cantidad) as compras, 
            0 as ventas, 
            0 as comision
    FROM compra
    GROUP BY moneda
    UNION ALL
    SELECT moneda, 
           0 as compras, 
           SUM(cantidad) as ventas, 
           SUM(comision) as comision
    FROM venta
    GROUP BY moneda) t 
GROUP BY moneda;
```

Answer (score 0):

Averiguado... he conseguido hacerlo usando subconsultas:

```
SELECT C.moneda, SUM(COMPRAS - VENTAS) FROM
(select moneda, sum(cantidad) as COMPRAS from compra group by moneda) C
LEFT JOIN
(select moneda, sum(cantidad) + sum(comision) as VENTAS from  venta group by moneda) V
ON
c.moneda=v.moneda

GROUP BY
C.MONEDA
```